# Segmentation Fault Using strcat()

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strcat

I am having segmentation faults on my strcat in the code below:

```
csv* lines_into_csv(int m,char* array[LINES_MAX][COLUMNS]){
   char *first_string, *final_string;
   first_string = (char*)calloc(400,sizeof(char));
   final_string = (char*)calloc(400,sizeof(char));
   csv *earthquake = malloc(sizeof(csv)*LINES_MAX);
   int n, j;

   for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
     for(n = 0; n < COLUMNS; n++ ){
       if (array[j][n] != NULL) {
         if(n < 4){
           strcat(first_string, array[j][n]);
        }
        else if(n == 4){

          earthquake[j].mag = atof(array[j][n]);
        }
        else {

          strcat(final_string, array[j][n]);
        }
       }
     }
     earthquake[j].start_of_line = (char*)calloc(200,sizeof(char));
     earthquake[j].end_of_line = (char*)calloc(200,sizeof(char));
     earthquake[j].start_of_line = strdup(first_string);
     earthquake[j].end_of_line = strdup(final_string);
     free(first_string);free(final_string);
   }


   return earthquake;
}
```

the csv type structure consists of two char* and a float which is the number from where I am sorting the file.

Comment: `strcat(first_string, tmp);` - you have not initialised `first_string` which is not done by `malloc()` and `strcat()` is expecting to find a nul terminator. If it doesn't find one in `first_string` it will keep ploughing through memory until it does, then who knows where it will copy your other string to?  Same thing with `final_string` and maybe others too, since you `malloc()` loads of stuff then proceed to work with it without initializing anything.

Comment: that might be.... what do you suggest to solve it?

Comment: Side-note: That `sizeof(char*)` is completely redundant. You should use `sizeof(char)`, or simply `1` (as this is the size of a `char` **by definition**).

Comment: By the way, `strcat` expects as arguments two pointers to **null-terminated** strings. You are calling this function with arguments that are pointing to valid memory segments, but those segments are not initialized with null-terminated data. This yields undefined behavior.

Comment: I made the change to `calloc()` and still got the same error

Comment: What about `strdup(array[j][n]);` was `array[][]` initialised?

Comment: thanks barack I addressed that change of `sizeof(char*)` thanks

Comment: My second comment (about you not passing null-terminated strings to `strcat`) is a lot more critical with regards to the question at hand.

Comment: yes the array has been initialized and it works with another function that prints the whole file already... I'm just trying to get it into this structure so it would be easier to sort.

Comment: how would correct that barack?

Comment: You double-free `tmp` every time that `array[j][n]` is `NULL`.  In fact `tmp` is redundant, you can use `array[j][n]` where you are currently using `tmp` . Allocating a copy of it is worse than useless.

Comment: thanks matt I will add your suggestion!

Comment: I have a question: how does `m` which controls the loop and indexing, relate to `LINES_MAX` which is used to allocate the `struct` memory?

Comment: well m is the number of lines in the file. I read the file and with a variable count the number of lines in it. then pass that variable in with the array that contains the file ordered by columns... that is why is multidimensional.

Comment: You dismissed my answer without even taking it in. Your latest edit *still* allocates memory to `earthquake[j].start_of_line` and immediately overwrites this pointer with one returned from `strdup()`. And why are you writing `first_string = NULL;final_string = NULL;` and not passing them to `free()`? I give up.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes I have been trying to change thins around to make it work... that is why i change the `free()` you answer was relater to `strdup()` which is not giving me a segmentation fault. If you like  could send you the code and the file so you have a better idea of the structure of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code here

```
csv *earthquake = malloc(sizeof(csv*)*LINES_MAX);
```

you are allocated an array of pointers to csv structs but you seem to assume that you can access objects of struct csv here:

```
earthquake->start_of_line = (char*)calloc(200,sizeof(char));
earthquake->end_of_line = (char*)calloc(200,sizeof(char));
```

you probably meant

```
csv *earthquake = malloc(sizeof(csv)*LINES_MAX);
```

**EDIT:**

Check the in-parameter that the lengths in it do not exceed the length you allocated. Also make sure the in-strings are properly 0 terminated.

Comment: yes sir! I meant that... however it still didnt' solve my `strcat()` problem

Comment: Checked you string lengths? No.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your use of `strcat()` because you are not initializing any of the strings you use as a target.

```
strcat(first_string, tmp);
...
strcat(final_string, tmp);
```

`strcat()` expects to find a nul terminator to append then next string at. If it doesn't find one it will keep ploughing through memory until it does, then who knows where it will copy your other string to?

One solution would be to use `calloc()` which writes `0` to the memory it allocates.

There is another problem too, memory leaks. You have allocated memory here - but only for the first array element.

```
earthquake->start_of_line = malloc( 100*sizeof(char*));
earthquake->end_of_line = malloc( 200*sizeof(char*));
```

which leads to memory leak when you soon after you do

```
earthquake[j].start_of_line = strdup(first_string);
earthquake[j].end_of_line = strdup(final_string);
```

You should know that `strdup()` allocates more memory and returns its pointer, which you then overwrite the original pointer returned by `malloc()`, so it will be impossible to free that memory, since you no longer have the pointers.

Moving on to the function argument `array[][]` which you are using for `dup()`, was that initialised or is it, too, random?

Comment: sorry but this is wrong. no errors from stardup or my initialization on the structure... calloc has been implemented as suggested and didnt solve the segmentation fault.

Comment: also these strings have been working the same way in another function that I have running to print all the values

Comment: Yes, I removed that part, but the memory leak still holds since you overwrite the `earthquake->start_of_line=...` (which was for `earthquake[0]`) with `earthquake[j].start_of_line = ...` (and `end_of_line`).

Comment: that doesnt have anything to do with `strcat()`. it would give me errors on `strdup()` which is not...

Comment: And, I don't understand why you say my answer is wrong about not initialising string memory before calling `strcat()`, which was independently commented by @barakmanos

Comment: well my strings are being initialized. tmp is a duplicate of the array string which exist and has a null at the end of it. I know that for a fact. the only one that might not have been initialized correctly is. first_string and final_string, but the `calloc()` didn't solve it because I made that change already and ran it.  I also modified the code from the post so you could evaluate it again.

Comment: The answer from @CyberSpock is good, but that does not mean there is nothing wrong with your uninitialised strings. Also better check your string lengths before using `strcat()` and/or use a safer version.

Comment: none of your answers address the real problem... which is the strcat(). segmentation fault.

Comment: What about the concatenated string length? BTW you will actually be getting a massive memory leak with `tmp=strdup()` because you call it in the inner loop `n` but you only `free(tmp)` in the outer loop `j`.

Comment: ok I just removed tmp completely as a variable! so it would be less confusion.